# How to compile C ping program writen by Mike Muuss on Windows

Tags: c, sockets, icmp

I have recently found **[this code](http://pastebin.com/VLgJnxVn)** which is the original ping source code by Mike Muuss.

I would like to have a similar source code **in C** for compiling it on a Windows machine.

- Is it worthwhile (or even possible) to modify this source code so that it will compile on a Windows machine ?
- Or are there any alternatives for this ?

I am not familiar with how to fake Berkeley style sockets and ICMP under Windows so I would really like some advices.

I know that there are some several lines written there, but if somebody could explain me a step by step process for achieving this it would be great.

Comment: I thought ping was already installed on windows

Comment: It might be, but I need an alternative of that code so I can implement it in an application

Comment: There is really not much to 'fake' to get Berkeley style sockets.  The big thing is that you need to call `WSAStartup` early in your program.  Other than that it is fairly straight forward.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for an example of using `socket` in a windows application.  Also, you can see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx about using raw sockets in a Windows application

Comment: There is a Windows API ping function `IcmpSendEcho` see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366050%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/src/games/ping/ping.c.htm

Comment: Thanks @thurizas and the rest of you guys. I'll try to compile it and come with an update.

Comment: I tried to compile that using gcc and it gave me this error: `fatal error: mmlite.h: No such file or directory. #include <mmlite.h> compilation terminated`

Comment: "mmlite.h", from a quick google search, is found at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/include/mmlite.h.htm.  If you are using gcc you might run in to difficulties due to there being code specific to Microsoft's compiler.  In addition to mmlite.h, you will also need the file that contains the implementation of the functions declared in mmlite, see http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/

Comment: Unfortunately, after I tried your code, @thurizas , It asked for a lot of libraries and I tried adding as many as I could but it would take me a lot of time to do this for all `.h files`

Comment: It is a microsoft research project after all :)  You might be able to take that code as a starting point to write your own, or investigate IcmpSendEcho as 'Weather Vane' suggests.  BTW, are you using gcc (either mingw or cygwin) or visual studio?  depending on what tool chain you are using you may have more or less luck.

Comment: I'm using gcc in combination with mingw. But I also tried Visual Studio.